# When AsyncTask which will update UI in onPostExecute is running, Operating UI will cause ANR

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-anr-dialog

Here is my code:

```
AsyncTCPReqTaskCommon task = new AsyncTCPReqTaskCommon(ip, port, new 
TCPReqCallBackCommon() {
   @Override
   public void onReceiveSuccess(String result{
       tvText.setText(result);
   }

   @Override
   public void onReceiveFailure() {
   }
});

task.execute(sendCmd);
```

`onReceiveSuccess` will be called in `onPostExecute`. The async network request costs 3~4 seconds. When the async task is running, sliding the UI will cause ANR. When I comment out this line `tvText.setText(result);`, the ANR will not appear.

The async task is not running in UI thread, why the ANR will appear? And what is the correct way to update `TextView`? Thanks in advance!

My UI does not support slide. The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.mobile.mytestapp.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="ReqNet"
    android:onClick="ReqNet"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

some log：

```
03-05 14:33:47.108 12255-12266/com.mobile.mytestapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.100ms
03-05 14:33:47.111 12255-12266/com.mobile.mytestapp I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6(384B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 14MB/14MB, paused 9.179ms total 34.364ms
03-05 14:33:59.773 12255-12255/com.mobile.mytestapp I/Choreographer: Skipped 762 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: Does your UI after sliding depends on the data received from AsyncTask ? If so, it may be an issue. Please post the error log.

Comment: Please post your logcat.

Comment: My UI does not support slide, it's a simple xml.

Comment: can you try to put runOnUIThread in onReceiveSuccess.

Comment: runOnUIThread does not works

Comment: please share your `AsyncTCPReqTaskCommon` code

Comment: you need to post your onPostExecute code

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone. I think I have found the reason. In my AsyncTCPReqTaskCommon, I new a 1M buffer from heap to receive network response. After the network operation, a GC is caused, it will lock the variable tvText. This GC takes too long time, the "tvText.setText(result);" can not be execute. So, a ANR appear! I have tried reduced the buffer size, the ANR does not appear!